# Revit API. Is there any way to retrieve column name of selected cell in a schedule?

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit

I`m working on c# for Revit 2019. I am trying to change value of selected cells in a schedule by changing parameter of a certain name. And it's work fine, but now I need to change parameter depends on selected column name in a table. Example of current code is:

```cs
            UIDocument uidoc = commandData.Application.ActiveUIDocument;
            var selection = uidoc.Selection;
            var ids = selection.GetElementIds();
            var doc = uidoc.Document;

            ViewSchedule view = doc.ActiveView as ViewSchedule;

            if (view == null) {
                return Result.Cancelled;
            }

            TableData table = view.GetTableData();
            TableSectionData section = table.GetSectionData(SectionType.Body);

            using (var transaction = new Transaction(doc, "Change param"))
            {
                transaction.Start();

                foreach (var id in ids)
                {
                    var el = doc.GetElement(id);
                    var param = el.LookupParameter("Number");
                    param.Set("TempValue");
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }

            return Result.Succeeded;
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't get selected cells of a schedule from `uidoc.Selection` as this contains what *elements* are selected.  You can get the data from the table and create your own in a `DataGridView` (WinForms) or `DataGrid` (WPF).  Then you know what cells are selected by the user.